# addon search available?

Tags: add-on

dumb newby question: Is there a single website one can visit to do a search for an addon that does a desired effect? For just an example, to do a search for a modifier that adds window shutters to a wall.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From that example, you seem to be looking for kitbashes/models. Kitbashes are essentially prebuilt parts that are typically focused around a specific style or theme such as industrial, sci-fi, gothic etc. These can greatly speed up your workflow. You can try poking around for free ones, but unfortunately, most of the quality kitbash/models need to be paid for.

Another thing of note: you still need modelling experience to use them. I'm not aware of any addon/program that will essentially build an entire model for you.

One great source of free models is the [Sketchup 3D Warehouse](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/?hl=en). You're going to need a third-party program to convert the SketchUp files to importable ones for Blender. [i3DConverter](http://3doc.i3dconverter.com/) works for that.